# android asynctask result in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an **Activity A** and an AsyncTask, which does some computations and stores data in to the database. These operations takes around 3-5 seconds. An AsyncTask is called after pressing a button "Save" and new Activity B starts (this Activity B is not important). There is also **Activity C**, that loads data, which I stored from Activity A and AsyncTask. And here is my problem - if I start Activity C and AsyncTask still didn't finish storing data, I want to show loading animation until AsyncTask will finish and data can be loaded in activity.

I have a vision that AsyncTask in method onPostExecute will change global variable "boolean finished = true" and after start Activity C, I will periodically check, if variable is true. But I think, that it's not a right way.
So, what is the right way?
Thank you

Comment: Why not starting Activity C in `onPostExecute` itself??

Comment: @Xenolion because it is possible that user doesn't want to show Activity C yet

Comment: Then show a dialog and declare a global `boolean` `isFinished= false` in post execute change the variable to `true`. If the user clicks to go to `C` check first if the `isFinished = true` if not show a toast telling the user to wait!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in Activity C is check the database in `onResume` whether your expected result is already there or not. If it's there, simply show your result. If it's not there show your loading icon and register a broadcast receiver that listens for a specific event.

In `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask` you can than broadcast that specific event. When activity C receives that event it can simply recheck the database where the result will now be.

Comment: This will get tricky. Assume the activity shows loading because the data isn't there. It has a receiver attached for broadcasts. Now obviously you should always remove a receiver in onPause/onStop to avoid issues. Assume the user presses home before the activity received the broadcast. Now on re open, onCreate does not get called and progress is infinite because broadcast missed. So check for data in onResume too.

Comment: Yes it definitely depends on where you will add and remove your receiver, that's where the database check has to happen as well. I will update my answer to perform the step in `onResume` instead of `onCreate`.

Comment: @GlennCodes and what if I don't know expected result? I don't know how many records will be stored. My database will store id (of table), id_player, round_of_match, points, goals and other player's properties. After each match (button Save match is pressed), AsyncTask will start to save these records for every player in match